# Issues running web tests on MacOs with Firefox: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

The Browser opens, but it seems like the initialization fails to return an instance of the driver. Initially I was just trying to use the default firefox driver that comes with Selenium, however surfing the net I found a possible solution using the gecko driver and setting the desired capabilities to marionette. But I still get the same issue as detailed below:

**Environment Details:**

```
OS: macOs Sierra, 10.12.6
Browser: Firefox --> 55.0.3 (64-bit)
Driver: geckodriver
Selenium: 2.53.0
```

**StackTrace:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
ager    DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1506807895921   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1506807895924   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to /var/folders/9p/2htxqw413p57h8nlv3mzk0w96r_3bp/T/anonymous2657944051650289643webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com
1506807895925   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /var/folders/9p/2htxqw413p57h8nlv3mzk0w96r_3bp/T/anonymous2657944051650289643webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
1506807895925   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1506807895926   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping aushelper@mozilla.org to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1506807895927   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping clicktoplay-rollout@mozilla.org to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/clicktoplay-rollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1506807895928   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping e10srollout@mozilla.org to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1506807895928   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1506807895928   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping followonsearch@mozilla.com to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/followonsearch@mozilla.com.xpi
1506807895928   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping screenshots@mozilla.org to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
1506807895928   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org.xpi
1506807895928   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping webcompat@mozilla.org to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1506807895928   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on aushelper@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1506807895929   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on clicktoplay-rollout@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1506807895929   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on e10srollout@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1506807895929   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on firefox@getpocket.com in app-system-defaults
1506807895929   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on followonsearch@mozilla.com in app-system-defaults
1506807895930   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1506807895930   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1506807895930   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1506807895930   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1506807895931   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1506807895931   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {}
2017-09-30 14:44:56.051 firefox-bin[44193:336169] IMKInputSession presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : [self textInputContext]=0x12826f3a0 *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection from pid 0" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection from pid 0}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem
1506807896108   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/55.0.3/20170824053838/Darwin_x86_64-gcc3/en-US/release/Darwin%2016.7.0/default/default/update.xml
1506807896377   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1506807896775   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1506807896784   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /var/folders/9p/2htxqw413p57h8nlv3mzk0w96r_3bp/T/tmpaddon
1506807897933   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1506807897936   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /var/folders/9p/2htxqw413p57h8nlv3mzk0w96r_3bp/T/tmpaddon

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
    at com.move.lead.allocation.CommonTestBase.initialize(CommonTestBase.java:68)
    at com.move.lead.allocation.api.ApiTestBase.testExceutionPreChecks(ApiTestBase.java:89)
    at com.move.lead.allocation.api.ApiTestBase.intializetestMethod(ApiTestBase.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:590)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Related: [Selenium + FF : How to fix error, Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/20740/2840)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update your selenium jars as you are using ff 55.0 and also update geckodriver

Link for geckodriver : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Link for selenium jars: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Try it once and let me know if you have any concerns